# On adding of scroll controller inside listview floating and snap behaviour of CustomScrollView is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using NestedScrollView for snap behavior.

Widget Tree:-

NestedScrollView => TabView => CustomScrollView => SliverList

For load more when I am adding scroll controller floating behavior stop working

Comment: are you using NestedScrollView?

Comment: Please show your source code

Comment: Yes @Darish 
For load more I need scroll controller in list

Comment: you should not set scroll controller for inner listview as it would break outer nested scroll view functionality. Read the official docs. For load more functionality, you can use the ScrollNotification

Comment: You can use pull_to_refresh package to handle pull, load more data
in a TabView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not set your own `ScrollController` to `CustomScrollView` if the `CustomScrollView` is wrapped inside `NestedScrollView`.

> The "controller" and "primary" members should be left unset, so that the NestedScrollView can control inner CustomScrollView. If the "controller" property is set, then the inner CustomScrollView will not be associated with the NestedScrollView.

### Solution

You can use the the [NotificationListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html) to implement load more functionality.

Simply wrap your `CustomScrollView` with the `NotificationListener<ScrollUpdateNotification>` widget.

```
 NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
    if (scrollInfo.metrics.pixels ==
        scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {

      ///load next page here
      loadMore();

    }
  },
  child: CustomScrollView(
    // ...
  ),
),
```